# my variable is having a persistent null value outside the ValueEventListener

Tags: java, scope

I don't have much experience with Java. I need to get value from Firebase realtime database and return this value outside listener.
My code is:

```
     public void AtualizaTotaisUSU(){
      
         user_auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
         usuario_str = user_auth.getUid();
         usuario_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuario")
                  .child(usuario_str);
         VELusuario_ref = usuario_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usuario_class= snapshot.getValue(Usuario_Class.class);
            myDouble = usuario_class.getRetiradaTotal();
            // retiradaTotal is a Double type field of my firebase table and is setted to the 
               value of 7.0.
            // log just for check  the values
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: myDouble exw " + myDouble);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
       });
            // log just for check  the values
           Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: myDouble exe " + myDouble);

           usuario_ref.child("totalEnviado").setValue(myDouble);

        }
```

when i tried to update the "totalEnviado" field of my firebase table with **usuario_ref.child("totalEnviado").setValue(myDouble)**;i got the field erased from it, because myDouble value is "null" outside the listener. How can i fix this and update the field table with the correct valor 7.0.
The log results are:

```
      I/ContentValues: onDataChange: retir tot exe null
      I/ContentValues: onDataChange: retir tot exw 7.0
```

i am instantiating myDouble like

```
      private Double myDouble;
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Where did you declare this `private Double myDouble;`

Comment: Can you post some more code, specifically the variable declaration

Comment: Hi David Kariuki,  I refactored the code and declared the variables with the right scope. Thank you for the note.